# Why is the return buffer of DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock() 8 bytes longer than the input?

Tags: c#, cryptography, des

I'm implementing a Pseudo Random Bit Generator using DES. Each generated number relies on the encrypted number from the previous step. This is why I wanted to use ICryptoTransform insted of CryptoStream, but:

- I don't understand how `ICryptoTransform.TransformBlock()` works
- `ICryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock()` returns an array 8 bytes longer than the input (this is what bothers me - if i'm not wrong DES encrypts 64 bits and returns 64 bits)

Code:

```
Random random = new Random();
byte[] input = new byte[8];
random.NextBytes(input);
byte[] s = new DESCryptoServiceProvider()
    .CreateEncryptor()
    .TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, 8);
```

`s` is `byte[16]`, why not `byte[8]?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the input will be padded to the next block size using PKCS padding.
To disable padding you may do the following:

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider mDES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
mDES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```